# React.PureComponent doesn't work when the Component has children?

Tags: performance, reactjs, components, react-dom

It seems a common technic to use PureComponent to improve rendering perf in React. However, it seems not the case when using PureComponent who has children as props.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('re-render') 
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <div />
    </App>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  )
  setTimeout(render, 1000)
}

render()
```

The result is that console keeps logging 're-render' every 1s. It seems the children(`<div />`) is the only prop of above `App` component and never changes, why App still gets re-rendered?

Note: in case of any confusion, the question is the same as, why SCU(shouldComponentUpdate) hook of PureComponent above return **true** since no props seems changed?

Comment: may I ask why you are calling `render` inside `render`? you have already rendered you app when you did `ReactDOM.render(..)` and then you calling it again recursively. Ins't it that causes you app to be rerendered many times?

Comment: @margaretkru i intentionally trigger rerender for it to test the SCU of App pure component above. Note added :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 console.log(<div /> === <div />) // false
```

On every rerender of `<App />`, a **new** [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom) was created by `React.createElement(div, null)`, thus `this.props.children` will be different from `nextProps.children` though they look the same in [JSX](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG6ID0AfEQL5FA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0).

In fact, the real problem is that the reference(otherwise value if is primitive type) of `props.children` changes every time the parent re-renders and React.PureComponent compares props by reference embracing immutability.

Answer (score 8):

What happen here is you're actually calling `ReactDOM.render()`, Page (or App, I suppose you have a typo here) component is gonna trigger its `render()` function regardless of using `Component` or `PureComponent`.

The way PureComponent can help to reduce unnecessary rendering is when **there is a prop change**, PureComponent will do a shallow comparison on `this.props` and `nextProps` to determine if this PureComponent needs to call `render()`.

---

I just made this example for you:

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {value: 0}

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({value: Math.random()})
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PureChild value="fixed value"/>
        <ImpureChild value="fixed value"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class PureChild extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log('rendering PureChild')
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>
  }
}

class ImpureChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('rendering ImpureChild')
    return <div>{this.props.value}</div>
  }
}
```

Pay attention to this few things:

1. Both children are receiving a fixed props ("fixed value" string)
2. Every 1 second, the parent `<App />` change `value` state, thus it re-renders, causing all its children to re-render as well.
3. **But** since `<PureChild />` is a PureComponent, it does a shallow comparison on its old props and incoming new props, and notices both props are `"fixed value"`, and therefore it doesn't trigger render!

If you run this code and open up console, you'll see only 'rendering ImpureChild' every 1s, but 'rendering PureChild' will only appear once.

Comment: Note added, it's my bad to cause confusion, this might not be my question, but thanks for efforts!

Answer (score 2):

Now as per the documentation of `ReactDOM`

> `ReactDOM.render()` controls the contents of the container node you pass
>   in. Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called.
>   Later calls use React’s DOM diffing algorithm for efficient updates.
>
> `ReactDOM.render()` does not modify the container node (only modifies
>   the children of the container). It may be possible to insert a
>   component to an existing DOM node without overwriting the existing
>   children.

ReactDOM from second time onwards, just updates the React component with the diffing algorithm it uses else where, so Its not the ReactDOM, that causes the re-render then. You can verify this by add a `componentWillMount` method in the App Component and check that it is only called once

Now coming to the PureComponent. The docs state that

`React.PureComponent’s` `shouldComponentUpdate()` only shallowly compares the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce false-negatives for deeper differences. Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have simple props and state

So here is the catch, PureComponent may return false negatives for deeper differences. So when you try to compare `this.props.children` with `nextProps.children` for equality you will find that it returns `false` and hence the re-render is triggered again

Check this **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4rzl566xy)**

Comment: Thx for detailed answer first! Note added, I'm interested about the pure component part, would you mind elaborate a bit more on the last part of props.children, why this.props vs nextProps get changed?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of the React.PureComponent

1). PureComponent implement shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow props and state comparison, will check whether page needs to be re-render

2). If there is complex objects in props or state, then PureComponent will give false positive result, must have to run force update

3). Change in parent component will not update children, so PureComponent's children should also be PureComponent